# Audio lags or stutters playing Youtube videos in a floating WebView based on Chromium

Tags: android, webview, youtube, chromium

I'm working on an Android application with a floating WebView that plays Youtube videos using the Youtube's IFrame API. The floating view is implemented as a Service and it's always open while the user navigates through the different activities of the application, it also floats when the application is minimized.

The issue is have right now, is that the sound of the video lags or stutters when the view components are being rendered in the activities. This is the troubleshooting I've done:

- I made two simple activities, no network work behind, just a bunch of Buttons in their layout. The sound gets cut for a second or more when you navigate to these activities or go back.
- I've setup hardware accelerated property on my application and  to the WebView. These are the params I use to add the WebView to the WindowManager

  ```
  int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;

  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
          flags,
          PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  ```
- I've set the setLayerType to the WebView as LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE. The following is the setup code for the WebView

  ```
  WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
  settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

  AndroidInterface javascriptInterface = new AndroidInterface(this);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(javascriptInterface,         "AndroidFunction");
  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
  webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
  } else {
      webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  }
  ```
- I've also tried turning off hardware acceleration for the application, but the WebView needs it to play videos.
- I've loaded a Youtube video, without using their IFrame API and I've got the same issue.
- This is intestering, if I load a Vimeo video, the issue does NOT occur.
- The issue occurs in a Nexus 5 (Android version 6.0.1) but it DOES NOT occur in a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (Android version 4.2.2). This makes me think that the issue is related with Chromium, since WebView uses WebKit on all pre-4.4 devices, and do not use Chromium.

Does anybody have experienced this issue before? Any ideas will be useful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the end I found out the way to resolve this issue. I declared the service in a another process ( specifying the android:process attribute in the Android Manifest file). The communication between the two services have to be done using IPC (Android Interprocess Communication) with Messenger.